# Pointer: Read Access Violation - why?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a function which can be called in two variants.
The first one works fine, but the second gives a read acccess violation.

Somehow I do not see an error.
Do you see a mistake?

Thanks

```
void doSth(uchar *ptr, uint size, bool variant_one)
{
   uchar *buffer = new uchar[size];

   // Works
   if(variant_one) {
       for(uint i=0; i<size; i++) {
           buffer[i] = (*(ptr+1));
           ptr = ptr+2;
       }
   }
   else {
       uint16_t* ptr16 = (uint16_t*) &ptr;
       for(uint i=0; i<size; i++) {
           buffer[i] =(uchar) *(ptr16)>>4; // Gives Read Access Violation
           ptr16++;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: `&ptr` is the location of the argument, not its value.

Comment: you shouldn't use all those c-casts, they are hiding bugs

Comment: fwiw, also your first variant looks a bit odd. Like anything else pointers are passed by value, so it doesn't really do anything that the caller could observe (other than leaking `buffer`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  uint16_t* ptr16 = (uint16_t*) &ptr;
> ```

You reinterpret `ptr` as a pointer to `uint16_t`, but no such object exists at that address. Attempting to access the non-existing object results in undefined behaviour (at least until C++20; it introduces implicit creation of trivial objects in some cases).

```
uint16_t* ptr16 = (uint16_t*) &ptr;
   for(uint i=0; i<size; i++) {
       buffer[i] =(uchar) *(ptr16)>>4;
       ptr16++;
```

Assuming `uchar` is 8 bits wide type, there is no way that an array of `size` 8 bit objects would fit `size` number of 16 bit objects. You overflow the array.

Edit: All of the above would apply if you had written `(uint16_t*) ptr;` which would have made a bit more sense even though still broken. All of the above still apply to `&ptr` as well except that's in addition probably not what you intended.